# RF over-the-air signal loss inside an RF chamber

Tags: rf, antenna, frequency, testing, loss

For cabled/conducted testing, path loss between DUT & Test equipment is calculated from cumulative insertion loss from any adapters, co-axial cables, attenuator pads etc.

But for over-the-air/radiated testing, how can one calculate/characterize loss between a DUT antenna & test antenna inside the RF Chamber. I understand RF chamber is almost equivalent to Free Space, and there is a Free Space Path Loss (FSPL) associated based on Frequency & Distance, but would that suffice to calculate the loss?

Comment: Free space PathLoss is 22dB + 20*log10(distance/wavelength)

Comment: Ever heard of folk calibrating their test house equipment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and if your anechoic chamber is large enough, and well covered in [RAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation-absorbent_material), you can try backing up your transmitter in measured increments, and plotting the results at each step. You can then check your results against the free space model.